# Too little or too much maxpooling?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I am creating a `CNN` in Keras where `model.summary()` shows:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 62, 62, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 62, 62, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 31, 31, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 29, 29, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 29, 29, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 64)          36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 4, 4, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 2, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 17)                2193      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 17)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 128,337
Trainable params: 128,337
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The inputs are images of size $64\times64$. How can I find out if there is too much, too little or just right max-pooling layers? [This page](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/dnouri/nolearn/blob/master/docs/notebooks/CNN_tutorial.ipynb) explain it but I am not able to get it from Kera's output here.

Comment: I am not clear. Which parameter and what value should I keep in mind? Please give more details, maybe as an answer which I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using max-pooling is not a good idea on its own. The reason is that by employing that, you ignore $75$% of the information each time. If your input is a signal which is quite a small pattern, as the number you have referred, it is better not to use max-pool that much. Although the use of max-pooling adds relative spatial invariance to the objects in the input and is useful for classification tasks, the main reason it is employed nowadays is to reduce the number of parameters to train. For instance, for images which belong to $R^{224\times224}$, it is wise to use them for some layers due to lessening the number of training parameters significantly. For images with smaller sizes, the input signal on its own has a smaller number of entries, features, and by employing max-pooling, you are chiefly discarding information which may be necessary and prominent for generalisation. You are actually shrugging them off!

Comment: I understand now. What number(s) in `model.summary()` output may indicate this?

Comment: The part from you own code: `activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 29, 29, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 64)        0       `. As you can see the dimensions are diminished after pooling layer.

Comment: Finally they go down to `(MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 2, 64)   0`. What minimum number do you suggest in place of 2? Eight `(None, 8,8,64)`?

Comment: As I've mentioned, I suggest using pooling layers as few as possible. Try just one.

Comment: Does it matter if I keep it at the end or somewhere in the middle of convolution layers?

Comment: If you want to have it, I suggest inserting it in first layers. The last layers are somehow for concluding shapes from the extracted features coming from previous layers. If you use them in last layers, you may ignore more important features. Although this claim can be true or not based on the task, it's my gut feeling. *If you use them in last layers, you may ignore more important features* is true but should be investigated for the task.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. Just one last point - should one not use `Dropout` layer also after `Convolution` layer. If so, should it be put before or after `MaxPooling` layer?

Comment: Convolutional layers usually have a very small number of parameters compared to dense layers. Consequently, it is preferred to use the dropout **for** the dense layers. If you attempt to use it for convolutional layers you can use them either before or after pooling layer depending on your expectations. If you want to use your model for real time tasks and you insist upon using dropout for convolutional layers, you can put them after pooling layer which reduces the number of computation. You can use them before pooling layer too.

Comment: Great explanations.